# What is going on with llvm libcxx's source code?

Tags: c++, llvm

Seemingly all the source is in `include/` with files with no suffixes and the files in `src` are all empty with seemingly random chunks of code. Can anybody point me to a document that explains WTH is going on?

Comment: *"empty with seemingly random chunks of code"* What now? They can't be empty and contain code at the same time.

Comment: Post the repo link

Answer (score 2):

The header files that make up the C++ standard library simply have no extension. That's why you write `#include <vector>` and not `#include <vector.h>`. So that's why the header files have no extension.

Further due to the way templates work, function implementations for templates need to be placed in the header. So that's why a lot of the code lives in the header files.